# Windows 8 store app with sqlite database

Tags: windows, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Windows 8.1 Enterprise.

I am trying to make a data driven sample Windows 8 store app by following the example in the below link:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18417.windows-store-app-with-a-sqlite-database.aspx

As they suggest 2 references should be included.
They are

1. Sqlite for Windows Runtime
2. Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package

I have successfully installed both but I am not able to see the reference of "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package" in the "add reference dialogue".

Is there anything else I missed please help....

Awaiting reply.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is installed correctly, you will find the reference under *Windows -> Extensions* in the references dialog:

[image: reference dialog]

I should note that this is the same place where the SQLite reference is located.